# Best way to toggle leaflet tooltip depending on zoomlevel?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, leaflet, geojson

I love leaflet's new tooltips, but I hate clutter. I have three layers in a small project, and I'd like a certain set of each of the layers to have their tooltip visible at "all" zoomlevels (14+), a second tier—2—visible at 15+, and so on.

The three layers are `L.geoJSON`, so for now, I've got a property, `tier`, that is an integer (1–4).

This works:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
  // the three geoJSON layers
  var layers = [institutionsLayer, patronsLayer, essayPatronsLayer];
  layers.forEach(function(layer){
    var features = Object.keys(layer._layers);
    features.forEach(function(feature){
      if(map.getZoom() - layer._layers[feature].feature.properties.tier >= 13){
        layer._layers[feature].openTooltip();
      } else {
        layer._layers[feature].closeTooltip();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But this seems like an awful hack.

Is there an option or something for min and max zoom values for something to be visible?

I know there is on ArcGIS online and I think Carto.

It's in action here:

https://muziejus.github.io/mep-leaflet-mvp/